# Reading only the value from MongoDB database with C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am trying to read random data from my MongoDB database and use only the "word" value without the hole object like I have:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6161fecc143ec3890b16faea"), "word" : "create" }
```

My code is simple:

```
MongoClient dbClient = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
            var DB = dbClient.GetDatabase("ForTwitter");
            var collection = DB.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("user");
            var words = collection.AsQueryable().Sample(1).FirstOrDefault();  
            Console.WriteLine(words.ToString() + "\n");
```

So this is how my collection is JSON and looks like from mongo.exe:

```
> show collections
 user 
> db.getCollectionNames(); 
[ "user" ]
```

How can I only use the word value?

Comment: And? What's the Q?

Comment: Use `Get(“word”)`

Comment: It dosn't work with Get(), I get error CS1061

Comment: you should use projection. In Linq syntax that you use, it can be done via `Select`

Comment: Can you post what is your collection  looks like? Is it a  json or c# object?

Comment: My collections are JSON and look like this                                              `> show collections
user
> db.getCollectionNames();
[ "user" ]
>`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 var allItems = collection.AsBsonArray;
 var firstItem=allItems.FirstOrDefault();
var firstWord= firstItem["word"].AsString;
```

or

```
 foreach (var item in allItems)
    Console.WriteLine( $"Word : {item["word"].AsString}");
```

Comment: It gives me build error for both: `'IMongoCollection<BsonDocument>' does not contain a definition for 'AsBsonArray' and no accessible extension method 'AsBsonArray' accepting a first argument of type 'IMongoCollection<BsonDocument>' could be found`